# How to check if a sphere is fully inside another sphere

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

If I'm given the equation of any two spheres's how do I check if one is completely inside the other. Is there a formula, code or algorithm

What I don't want:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find out the center and the radius of each sphere. Let $C, R$ be the center and radius of the sphere with biggest radius, and $c, r$ be the center and radius of the smaller one. You must have $dist(C,c)\leq R-r$, where $dist(C,c)$ is the distance between $c$ and $C$. If you want to visualize why, draw the limiting case when the smallest sphere is tangential to the biggest sphere from within. That is when $dist(C,c)=R-r$.

Comment: If you look at the second image dist(C,c) < R-r, as well. I only want to flag spheres where one is **not** completely inside another

Comment: $dist(C,c)≤R−r$ implies spheres are inside one another. When that is not true, that is, when $dist(C,c)>R−r$,then spheres are not inside one another.

Comment: If $dist(C,c)\leq R-r$ then the centre of 1 circle is inside another but this does not mean that the whole circle is inside the other

Comment: My statement is correct. To guarantee only that the center of 1 circle is inside the other circle, you would use $dist(c,C)\leq R$. I suggest you draw out several examples to understand this. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much.